# send ERC20 tokens not working: invalid address

Tags: javascript, solidity

Here is my javascript code:
The address I'm sending it to is input address from user on app.
The caller (currently selected metamask address has enough ERC20 tokens)

```
lookupVoterInfo: function() {
   let toAddress = $("#voter-info").val();
   Voting.deployed().then(function(contractInstance) {
     contractInstance.transfer(toAddress, 10);
   })
```

MyERC20 Contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

import "../openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "../openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract MyERC20 is ERC20 {
    uint256 public INITIAL_SUPPLY = 20000;
constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MYT") {
        _mint(msg.sender, INITIAL_SUPPLY);
    }
}
```

error message:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a specific `toAddress` value that throws this error?

Comment: make a console.log of the `toAddress` before calling the transfer function and check if it is a valid address

Comment: `toAddress` needs to be 42 char long prefixed by `0x`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing the following:
You need to specify the gas fee and the account address.

contractInstance.approve(web3.currentProvider.selectedAddress, 100, {gas: 1000000, from: web3.eth.accounts[0]});
contractInstance.transferFrom(web3.currentProvider.selectedAddress, toAddress, 10, {gas: 1000000, from: web3.eth.accounts[0]});